# How many $m$ such that : $\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \left\lfloor\frac{m}{k}\right\rfloor$ be even?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, combinations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find how many $m \le 1000$ such that : 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \left\lfloor \frac{m}{k}\right\rfloor$$

be even ( $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the largest integer smaller than $x$.)

I think that one case is  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \left\lfloor \frac{m}{k}\right\rfloor$ is even if for every integer  $k$ ( $ 1 \le k \le m $) $\left\lfloor\frac{m}{k}\right\rfloor$ be even or the number of odd number be even  in $\sum\limits_{k=1}^m \left\lfloor\frac{m}{k}\right\rfloor$. $\big($ $
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n d(i)
$
where $d(\ )$ is the divisor function $\big)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**, further to the comments
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \left \lfloor \frac{m}{k} \right \rfloor=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}d(k) \tag{1}$$

- $m=1 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{1} \left \lfloor \frac{1}{k} \right \rfloor=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{1}d(k)=\color{blue}{1}$, i.e. $\color{red}{\{1\}}$ is the only perfect square or $\color{blue}{\left \lfloor \sqrt{1} \right \rfloor=1}$ in total.
- $m=2 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2} \left \lfloor \frac{2}{k} \right \rfloor=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2}d(k)=1+2=\color{blue}{3}$, i.e. $\color{red}{\{1\}}$ is the only perfect square or $\color{blue}{\left \lfloor \sqrt{2} \right \rfloor=1}$ in total.
- $m=3 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{3} \left \lfloor \frac{3}{k} \right \rfloor=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{3}d(k)=1+2+2=\color{blue}{5}$, i.e. $\color{red}{\{1\}}$ is the only perfect square or $\color{blue}{\left \lfloor \sqrt{3} \right \rfloor=1}$ in total.
- $m=4 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4} \left \lfloor \frac{4}{k} \right \rfloor=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}d(k)=1+2+2+3=\color{blue}{8}$, i.e. $\color{red}{\{1, 4\}}$ are the only perfect squares or $\color{blue}{\left \lfloor \sqrt{4} \right \rfloor=2}$ in total.
- $m=5 \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{5} \left \lfloor \frac{5}{k} \right \rfloor=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{5}d(k)=1+2+2+3+2=\color{blue}{10}$, i.e. $\color{red}{\{1, 4\}}$ are the only perfect squares or $\color{blue}{\left \lfloor \sqrt{5} \right \rfloor=2}$ in total.

Is the pattern visible now? It should be easy to show it by induction.

Comment: answer is  exactlly all numbers such that ${\left \lfloor \sqrt{n} \right \rfloor=2k}$ ?

Comment: Yes! Or $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \left \lfloor \frac{m}{k} \right \rfloor$ is even $\iff \left \lfloor \sqrt{m} \right \rfloor$ is even. This should help you to answer "how many $m \leq 1000$ ... are even".

Comment: ${\left \lfloor \sqrt{m} \right \rfloor} \le 31$ then answer is 15.

Comment: You will have to go through all $m \in \{1,2,3,...,1000\}$ or try to reveal another pattern, like $m \in \{4,5,...,8\}$, $m \in \{16,17,...,24\}$, $m \in \{36,17,...,48\}$ ... all give even $\left \lfloor \sqrt{m} \right \rfloor$.